# .NET MVC 4 HTTP Post Data as JSON object

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to create a simple blogging application and I have Register and Login functionality working fine. The problem is that when creating a "Blog" entry, the blog has a custom control called Tags, which are just an array of tags for that blog post. However, the Razor engine does not have a `@Html.ControlFor()` like thing for a list, so I am hijacking the form and doing my own AJAX call using JSON:

```
{ 
  "Title" : "mytitle",
  "Content" : "some content",
  "Tags" : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
}
```

I have a BlogViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class BlogViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

and a controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(BlogViewModel bvm)
        {
           /* This is where I want to build of a BlogEntry object and save it to the DB */

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The thing is that my BlogViewModel in the PostBack has all null values except for the Title property for some reason.  What is the correct way to handle a JSON object like the one above so that I can save a BlogEntry properly?

Comment: What's the mechanism you are using to deserialize json string?

Comment: I am not deserializing anything right now. I am trying to figure out the best way.. Do I serialize the JSON into a string on the client? or do I send the JSON object directly? This is what I dont know

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to bind to the model via Razor. Here is how you do it:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Tags[i].TagName)
}
```

assuming your Tag model looks like this:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

This will bind the collection of tags to your model. However I'm not sure this is the correct approach to your problem since I assume that you want to add X many tags dynamically. Right?

Comment: yes, but at the Creation of a blog, Model.Tags.Count is 0.. So how do I create a new one.

Comment: Like I said if you are adding them dynamically then your best bet is to use some of existing jquery tag libraries like these:
http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager
http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Answer (score 0):

## Try this out:-

Use `IModelBinder` interface

```
public class Tag
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class BlogViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class BlogViewModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        BlogViewModel model;

        if (controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var form = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.ToString();
            model = serializer.Deserialize<BlogViewModel>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(form));
        }
        else
        {
            model = (BlogViewModel)ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

**JS:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $tags = [];

    var tag = function (TagName) {
        this.TagName = TagName;
    }

    $tags.push(new tag("a"));
    $tags.push(new tag("b"));
    $tags.push(new tag("c"));

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:3938/Blog/Create",
            ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            type: "post",
            data:JSON.stringify({ 
                        "Title" : "mytitle",
                        "Content" : "some content",
                        "Tags": $tags
                    })
        });
    });

</script>
```

and inside your Global.asax.cs file add `ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(BlogViewModel)] = new BlogViewModelBinder();`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(BlogViewModel)] = new BlogViewModelBinder();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattHintzke Does this answer your query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your ajax call.

```
data: JSON.stringify(model),
contentType: 'application/json'
```